# BrowseDialog and InstallDirDlg wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have an InstallDirDLG and i need other  browse dialog, the problem is when i select the path in second browse dialog also change the installdir path.

This is the control code:

```
<Control Id="IISLogDirectoryEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="45" Y="100" Width="220" Height="18" Disabled="yes" Property="IISLOGDIRECTORY" Indirect="yes" />
<Control Id="IIsLogDirectoryExplorer" Type="PushButton" X="267" Y="100" Width="56" Height="18" Text="Explorar..." />
```

And this is the publish:

```
<Publish Dialog="DirectoriesDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[IISLOGDIRECTORY]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DirectoriesDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="2"><![CDATA[NOT IISLOGDIRECTORY]]></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DirectoriesDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="FtpDlg" Order="3">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DirectoriesDlg" Control="IIsLogDirectoryExplorer" Property="_IISBrowseProperty" Value="[IISLOGDIRECTORY]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DirectoriesDlg" Control="IIsLogDirectoryExplorer" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="IISBrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some snippets of the code you use will definitely help to answer this...

Comment: I think the problem is that the property IISLOGDIRECTORY by default has installation path, but if I put another default value generate an error that the path does not exist in the directory table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use different property name for the second browse dialog and set that property value to some default location.

For example:

```
<Control Id="TestPathEdit"
         Type="PathEdit"
         X="120"  Y="157" Width="160" Height="18"
         Property="TESTPROPERTY"/>
<Control Id="TestBrowse"
         Type="PushButton"
         X="290" Y="157" Width="56" Height="17"
         Text="Browse">
    <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty"
             Value="TESTPROPERTY"
             Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog"
             Value="BrowseDlg"
             Order="2">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

and the default property value

```
<Property Id="TESTPROPERTY" Value="C:\Test"/>
```

Comment: I've tried this and when select the path i get error 2727:

A property is being used as the destination path of a component, but that property does not exist in the Directory table.

Comment: @Caotz: The error is because you might not have entry for the TESTPROPERTY value in the directory structure in the main wxs file(i.e Product.wxs)       Add entry for this property and try....                                           Example:  <Directory Id="TESTPROPERTY" Name="TestDir">
          </Directory>

Comment: I thought when add a directory in the directory structure, created a empty directory, but it is not like that.

Now work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @vinay Thank you for your sample code! I've been looking for a working example of PathEdit for a couple of days. Now it works. Fantastic! +1